# How to generate a unique ID for each group based on relative date interval in R using dplyr?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, datediff, cumsum

I have a cohort of data with multiple person visits and want to group visits with a common ID based on person # and the time of the visit. The condition is if an start is within 24 hours of a the previous exit, then I want those to have the same ID.

Sample of what data looks like:

```
dat <- data.frame(
Person_ID = c(1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4),
Admit_Date_Time = as.POSIXct(c("2017-02-07 15:26:00","2017-04-21 10:20:00", 
"2017-04-22 12:12:00", "2017-10-16 01:31:00","2017-01-24 02:41:00","2017-    01-24 05:31:00", "2017-01-28 04:26:00", "2017-12-01 01:31:00","2017-12-01 
01:31:00"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),
Discharge_Date_Time  = as.POSIXct(c("2017-03-01 11:42:00","2017-04-22 
05:56:00",
"2017-04-26 21:01:00",
"2017-10-18 20:11:00",
"2017-01-27 22:15:00",
"2017-01-26 15:35:00",
"2017-01-28 09:25:00",
"2017-12-05 18:33:00",
"2017-12-04 16:41:00"),format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" ),
Visit_ID = c(1:9))
```

this is what I tried to start:

```
dat1 <- 
dat %>%
arrange(Person_ID, Admit_Date_Time) %>%
group_by(Person_ID) %>%
mutate(Previous_Visit_Interval = difftime(lag(Discharge_Date_Time, 
1),Admit_Date_Time, units = "hours")) %>%
mutate(start = c(1,Previous_Visit_Interval[-1] < hours(-24)), run = 
cumsum(start))

dat1$ID = as.numeric(as.factor(paste0(dat1$Person_ID,dat1$run)))
```

Which is almost right, except it does not give the correct ID for visit 7 (person #3).  Since there are three visits and the second visit is entirely within the first, and the third starts within 24 hours of the first but not the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a way to shorten this, but here's an approach using `tidyr::gather` and `spread`. By gathering into long format, we can track the cumulative admissions inside each visit. A new visit is recorded whenever there's a new `Person_ID` or that `Person_ID` completed a visit (cumulative admissions went to zero) at least 24 hours prior.

```
library(tidyr)
dat1 <- dat %>%
  # Gather into long format with event type in one column, timestamp in another
  gather(event, time, Admit_Date_Time:Discharge_Date_Time) %>%

  # I want discharges to have an effect up to 24 hours later. Sort using that.
  mutate(time_adj = if_else(event == "Discharge_Date_Time", 
                            time + ddays(1), 
                            time)) %>%
  arrange(Person_ID, time_adj) %>%

  # For each Person_ID, track cumulative admissions. 0 means a visit has completed. 
  #   (b/c we sorted by time_adj, these reflect the 24hr period after discharges.)
  group_by(Person_ID) %>%
  mutate(admissions = if_else(event == "Admit_Date_Time", 1, -1)) %>%
  mutate(admissions_count = cumsum(admissions)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

  # Record a new Hosp_ID when either (a) a new Person, or (b) preceded by a 
  #   completed visit (ie admissions_count was zero).
  mutate(Hosp_ID_chg = 1 * 
           (Person_ID != lag(Person_ID, default = 1) |   # (a)
            lag(admissions_count, default = 1) == 0),    # (b)
         Hosp_ID = cumsum(Hosp_ID_chg)) %>%

  # Spread back into original format
  select(-time_adj, -admissions, -admissions_count, -Hosp_ID_chg) %>%
  spread(event, time)
```

Results

```
> dat1
# A tibble: 9 x 5
  Person_ID Visit_ID Hosp_ID Admit_Date_Time     Discharge_Date_Time
      <dbl>    <int>   <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>             
1         1        1       1 2017-02-07 15:26:00 2017-03-01 11:42:00
2         1        2       2 2017-04-21 10:20:00 2017-04-22 05:56:00
3         1        3       2 2017-04-22 12:12:00 2017-04-26 21:01:00
4         2        4       3 2017-10-16 01:31:00 2017-10-18 20:11:00
5         3        5       4 2017-01-24 02:41:00 2017-01-27 22:15:00
6         3        6       4 2017-01-24 05:31:00 2017-01-26 15:35:00
7         3        7       4 2017-01-28 04:26:00 2017-01-28 09:25:00
8         4        8       5 2017-12-01 01:31:00 2017-12-05 18:33:00
9         4        9       5 2017-12-01 01:31:00 2017-12-04 16:41:00
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much for your help, I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a data.table approach using an overlap-join

```
library( data.table )
library( lubridate )
setDT( dat )
setorder( dat, Person_ID, Admit_Date_Time )
#create a 1-day extension after each discharge
dt2 <- dat[, discharge_24h := Discharge_Date_Time %m+% days(1)][]
#now create id
setkey( dat, Admit_Date_Time, discharge_24h )
#create data-table with overlap-join, create groups based on overlapping ranges
dt2 <- setorder( 
  foverlaps( dat, 
             dat, 
             mult = "first", 
             type = "any", 
             nomatch = 0L 
             ), 
  Visit_ID )[, list( Visit_ID = i.Visit_ID, 
                     Hosp_ID = .GRP ), 
             by = .( Visit_ID )][, Visit_ID := NULL]

#reorder the result
setorder( dt2[ dat, on = "Visit_ID" ][, discharge_24h := NULL], Visit_ID )[]

#    Visit_ID Hosp_ID Person_ID     Admit_Date_Time Discharge_Date_Time
# 1:        1       1         1 2017-02-07 15:26:00 2017-03-01 11:42:00
# 2:        2       2         1 2017-04-21 10:20:00 2017-04-22 05:56:00
# 3:        3       2         1 2017-04-22 12:12:00 2017-04-26 21:01:00
# 4:        4       3         2 2017-10-16 01:31:00 2017-10-18 20:11:00
# 5:        5       4         3 2017-01-24 02:41:00 2017-01-27 22:15:00
# 6:        6       4         3 2017-01-24 05:31:00 2017-01-26 15:35:00
# 7:        7       4         3 2017-01-28 04:26:00 2017-01-28 09:25:00
# 8:        8       5         4 2017-12-01 01:31:00 2017-12-05 18:33:00
# 9:        9       5         4 2017-12-01 01:31:00 2017-12-04 16:41:00
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, unfortunately data table usage is way above me and I can't get this to work on my actual code (see below error). The dplyr post is what I need though. Thanks anyways! Error in foverlaps(dat, dat, mult = "first", type = "any", nomatch = 0L) : 
  All entries in column Admit_date_time should be <= corresponding entries in column discharge_24h in data.table 'x'"

Comment: @r_newb that error means that some of your discharge_date_times are BEFORE your admit_date_times.... you might want to check that! Correct them, or filter them out.